# vim search and copy lines including pattern

Tags: vim

I use the following VIM command, to copy all lines including a pattern to the end of the file
`:g/pattern/t$`
But I also want the previous or the line below of the matched line copied too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In:

```
:g/pattern/t$
```

`:t` is an ex command which, like all ex commands, can take a range.

The following command would copy lines 1-13 after the last line:

```
:1,13t$
```

Beside absolute line numbers, you can use relative numbers:

```
:-3,+5t$
```

and, really, anything that can be translated to a line number:

```
:?foo?,'et$
```

In your case, you can use a range to tell Vim to copy the marked line, the one above (`-1`), and the one below (`+1`):

```
:g/pattern/-1,+1t$
```

Or, slightly shorter:

```
:g/pattern/-,+t$
```